# Python scripts produce no error message when failing due to an error, even after version upgrade and rebuilding virtual environments. How to remedy?

Tags: python, output, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Roughly 6 months ago without any obvious cause, all python scripts on my machine have stopped outputting an error message when hitting an error condition. They output my normal logging and/or print statements as intended and when the code runs successfully there is no issue, however if an error occurs then the code will simply stop with no additional output. This is the same for scripts called ad-hoc as well as cron (which lock their output to files).

I am calling the python scripts from WSL2 (Ubuntu). This affects all scripts called on this machine regardless of contents.

I use pipenv for environment management, so scripts are called with `pipenv run python3 path/to/script`, but the behaviour is identical regardless if it's called with cron or ad-hoc.

I have recently moved my codebase to Python 3.12 (from 3.8) and rebuilt all my virtual environments (using pipenv) -- I had thought that this might solve the issue, however it has not. I've dockerised this project since posting this, and when it runs in the container it also prints no error output.

The single exception to this issue is that code executed in Jupyter notebooks is able to output error messages as normal.

Could anyone suggest approaches I might take to fixing this and getting error messages printing normally again? I've dealt with it for quite a long time, since my logging lets me know where the code as failed, but I'd definite like (and it'd make my life easier!) to get it working again.

Thanks :)

Comment: It sounds like anything directed to `stderr` is not being returned. In a regular WSL Ubuntu terminal, if you type `echo "Hello" >&2`, do you get `Hello` output on the next line? This might help diagnose whether it's just Python error outputs or more generally any output to `stderr` that is not showing up.

Comment: @MattPitkin This prints the string as output and also prints the output identically when called from within a python script:

```
:~$ echo "Hello" >&2
Hello
:~$ echo 'import subprocess; subprocess.Popen(["bash", "-c", "echo \"Hello\" >&2"])' > test_script.py
:~$ python3 test_script.py
Hello
```

Comment: Does anything in this thread seem familiar/give you any clues https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/365? Are your scripts using `logging`? What shell are you using?

Comment: @MattPitkin none of this seems to apply and all the code examples execute correctly. I have done a little more exploration in the process and I notice that some errors (such as an unterminated string literal `SyntaxError`) will output errors, while others won't. Most notably the `ProgrammingError` messages that are returned from database connectors when there is an error in the database side, but also this simple example won't output it's `IndexError` error message `[1,2,3][3]` (which outputs normally in a Jupyter example).

Comment: Another thing I notice: I've dockerised this project now, and when it runs in the container it also prints no error output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as an answer as this turned out to solve the problem --

I'd been asked to wrap the code in a large try/except to put some manual error logging onto a database, this was what was causing the problem.

Have removed that, will find a better way to do it. Problem solved.

Comment: If you used a bare `except` clause, this is a great demonstration of why that is dangerous -- you should only catch the specific errors you expect to encounter (or want to handle) from that block of code